# Does $\Bbb Q_p^×$ have index $n$ subgroup?

Tags: group-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, class-field-theory

Let $n$ be arbitrary positive integer.
Does $\Bbb Q_p^×$ have index $n$ subgroup?

If I could prove this, from local class field theory, I can say $\Bbb Q_p$ has arbitrary degree of extension.

I know $\Bbb Q_p^×$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z×\Bbb Z_p×\Bbb Z/（p-1）\Bbb Z$ using formal logarithm.

Reference is also appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Isn't it obvious that at least one of the factors in the direct product you wrote does have a subgroup of index $n$ for arbitrary $n$? Isn't it very easy to conclude from there?

Comment: Note that it’s easy (and actually fundamental to local CFT) to directly construct a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ of arbitrary degree.

Comment: This is also obvious if we admit unratified extension of Qp is gained by adding n-th root (n is coprime to p) of unity to Qp,